# How to configure serenity reporting to include results from all parallel tests?

Tags: serenity-bdd

I have a project where I have configured cucumber to run in parallel on browserstack. Each test will run and complete but the auto generated serenity report includes results for only one of the tests. Is there a way the report can include all results from each individual test that run in parallel?

Comment: Also, how can the report distinguish each result from the browser it is running on?

Comment: I have included serenity:aggregate which has resolved the parallel tests collating in one report. However, each browserstack test is not seperated in the report. This means my report collects results from a test running on one of the browsers.

Any ideas on this?